# find file count in a directory of any specific date provided by user using shell script

Tags: scripting

While doing this using below command

```
find /tmp type -f ls|grep "Any date"|wc -l

*Any date =May 15 or May 5
```

it gives the correct result for May 15 but for May 5 it does not give any result because in ls command there is extra space prior to 5 th may.

How to resolve these space issue so that my script work for both the values?

Answer (score 1):

Search for month followed by 1 **or more** spaces.  e.g.

```
find . -type f -ls | grep -E "May +5"
```

A more elegant approach (and to avoid the [don't parse ls](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls%20%22don't%20parse%20ls%22%20pitfalls) pitfalls) would be to use

```
find . -type f -newermt 2018-05-05 ! -newermt 2018-05-06 | wc -l
```